# Python polars speed issue

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-polars

I have python code that runs fast on my laptop, but terrible slow on a desktop. The desktop is new with a better cpu and more ram. Why is the same code slower?

I use polars and this is my code:

```
def remove_timezone(df: pl.DataFrame, col: str = 't'):
    return df.with_column(
        pl.col(col).apply(
            lambda x: x.astimezone(  # type: ignore
                pytz.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)  # type: ignore
        ).alias(col))

df = remove_timezone(df, 't')
```

On the laptop, with a 11th Gen intel core i7, 4 cores 8 logical processors and 16 gb of ram this takes 6 seconds. On the desktop with an AMD  Ryzen Threadripper Pro 24 cores 48 logical processors and 128 gb of ram it takes 134.1 second.

To reproduce this problem:

```
def setup():
    t = [datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 1, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)))] * 51824
    return pl.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'t': t}))

remove_timezone(setup())
```

Using pandas:

```
def remove_timezone(df):
    df['t'].apply(lambda x: x.astimezone(pytz.utc).replace(tzinfo=None))
```

the pandas solution it takes 5.1 seconds on the laptop and 0.2 seconds on the desktop.

EDIT:

To make it possible to compare the results a new environment is created. For now python 3.9.12 is used and polars version 0.15.8. The results are still the same.

I noticed that there is some "problem" in polars when using the date type `[datetime[ns, +01:00]`. For example when I do `df['t'].to_list()` it takes also a long time. If I do it after removing the timezone it is super fast.

Comment: Are you using different version of python/polars on the desktop/laptop? If you care about performance you shouldn't use `apply` with lambda, but instead use temporal expressions https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/timeseries.html

Comment: Hi, I use polars version 0.15.8 with python version 3.9.12 on the laptop and polars version 0.16.1 on de desktop with python version 3.10.9. Good tip to not use apply, but even if it is not the fastest approach I expect it to be faster on the desktop than on the laptop.

Comment: Perhaps it's a "performance regression" - the first step would be to test polars `0.15.8` on the desktop if possible.

Comment: What do you mean with performance regression? I installed it with 0.15.8 and it is still the same. I will try to install it with the same python version and let you know how that went.

Comment: @jqurious I updated the question, now both systems uses the same python and polar versions.

Comment: As in - perhaps something changed between polars `0.15.8` and `0.16.1` that caused the same code to run slower - but you've already ruled that out. Can you try time polars own methods? e.g. `.with_columns(pl.col("t").dt.cast_time_zone("UTC").with_time_zone(None))` as @0x26res has suggested.

Comment: This reads like and xy problem to me. Before comparing apply/lambda performance on different machines, I'd suggest to pick the right tool for the job. Try the built-in methods as @jqurious suggests. If you're missing a feature, maybe open an issue on the polars github (search issues first, there's a lot going on).

Comment: Thank you for your problem. To be honest I still think that exactly the same operation should result in comparable results and not the slower computer 22 times faster. This difference is more extreme when comparing the pandas result where the slower computer is 25 times slower. But the solution of @jqurious does not work for me: `df.with_columns(pl.col('t').dt.cast_time_zone('UTC').with_time_zone(None))` gives an attribute error and without `.with_time_zone(None)` it says `ComputeError: Could not parse timezone: 'UTC'`.

Comment: One potential troubleshooting step is to go through some benchmarks [Maybe these](https://github.com/h2oai/db-benchmark/tree/master/polars) on each machine and sort out which operations are slower/faster on each machine to help pinpoint.  Similar to your timezone finding and make a chart and publish it here and to the polars github.

Comment: Can anybody replicate the UTC `ComputeError`? I've tested from `0.15.8` upwards and it works for me...

Comment: Python polars and to lesser extent datetime version change fairly often. Unless you have a lot of other dependencies in your code you may use brain dead approach: just create i.e. a fresh conda env with latest python, polars and datetime on your desktop. If the problem persist, at least the developers will be imho more happy to resolve issues with the latest versions.